# Crear vistas en Django mediante clases

Tags: python, django

Tengo esta clase:

```
# Librerías de Django
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.db.models import Q
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

# Modelos y formularios
from .forms import ProductoForm
from .models import Producto, Facturas, Boletas

# Librerías para generar PDF
import os
import pdfkit
import tempfile
import webbrowser

# Para trabajar con clases
from django.views.generic import ListView

class MyView(ListView):
    model = None
    template_name = None
    vista = None  # define vista as a class attribute

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.model = kwargs.get('modelo', self.model)
        self.template_name = kwargs.get('vista', self.template_name)
        self.paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        busqueda = self.request.GET.get('buscar')
        campos_busqueda = ['id_boleta', 'total_boleta', 'usuario_FK__username']

        resultado = self.buscar_campos(busqueda, campos_busqueda)

        context = {'contenido': resultado}
        return render(self.request, self.template_name, context)

    def buscar_campos(self, busqueda, campos):
        modelo = self.model.objects.all()
        if busqueda:
            queries = [Q(**{campo: busqueda}) for campo in campos]
            query = queries.pop()
            for item in queries:
                query |= item
            modelo = modelo.filter(query).distinct()
        return modelo

    def generar_contenido_html(self, queryset):
        contenido = '<table>'
        contenido += '<thead><tr><th>Folio</th><th>Total</th><th>Vendedor</th><th>Fecha de emisión</th></tr></thead><tbody>'
        for objeto in queryset:
            contenido += f'<tr><td>{objeto.id_boleta}</td><td>{objeto.total_boleta}</td><td>{objeto.usuario_FK}</td><td>{objeto.fecha_emision.date()}</td></tr>'
        contenido += '</tbody></table>'
        return contenido

    def generar_pdf(self):
        with open('ProyecBazarApp/templates/ProyecBazarApp/include/plantilla.html', 'r') as f:
            html_content = f.read()

        # añadir los datos de la tabla al contenido HTML
        html_content = self.generar_contenido_html(self.get_queryset())

        # Guardar el contenido HTML en un archivo temporal
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.html', delete=False) as tmp_file:
            tmp_file.write(html_content.encode('utf-8'))
            tmp_file.flush()

            # Generar el PDF a partir del contenido del archivo temporal
            pdf_content = pdfkit.from_file(tmp_file.name, False)

            # Guardamos el contenido del PDF en un archivo temporal
            with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.pdf', delete=False) as pdf_file:
                pdf_file.write(pdf_content)
                pdf_file.flush()

                # Abrimos la vista previa del PDF en el navegador
                webbrowser.open_new_tab(pdf_file.name)

        # Cerrar manualmente el archivo temporal
        os.unlink(tmp_file.name)

    def get(self):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        context = {'contenido': queryset}
        response = render(request, self.template_name, context)

        # Generar PDF si se ha enviado la petición
        if self.request.method == 'POST' and 'informeBoletas_pdf' in self.request.POST:
            self.generar_pdf()
        return response
```

y estoy creando esta instancia:

```
from django.http import HttpRequest

# crear una instancia de HttpRequest
request = HttpRequest()

vista = 'ProyecBazarApp/informeBoleta.html'
modelo = Boletas
my_view = MyView(vista=vista, model=modelo)
response = my_view.get()`
```

y en el archivo urls.py:

```
 path('informe_Boletas/', views.my_view.as_view(), name='Boletas'),
```

El html:

```
{% extends "ProyecBazarApp/base.html" %}

{% block head %}
  <div class="barra_busqueda">
    <span class="text">Pagos</span>
    <form class="buscador" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="buscar" placeholder="Buscador" value="{{ request.GET.buscar }}">
    <button type="submit">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
    </button>
</form>
    <form class="buscador" method="GET">
    <input type="date" name="buscarFecha" value="{{ request.GET.buscarFecha }}">
    <button type="submit">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
    </button>
</form>
  </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Vendedor</th>
        <th>Fecha de emisión</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for boleta in page_obj %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ boleta.id_boleta }}</td>
        <td>{{ boleta.total_boleta }}</td>
        <td>{{ boleta.usuario_FK }}</td>
        <td>{{ boleta.fecha_emision.date }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
  
  <div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-backward-step"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-backward"></i>
            </a>
        {% endif %}
  
        <span class="current-page">
            Página {{ page_obj.number }} de {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}
        </span>
  
        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-forward"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-forward-step"></i>
            </a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
  </div>  
  <form method="post" class="generadorPDF">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" name="informeBoletas_pdf">Generar PDF</button>
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

No entiendo qué está mal y por qué no funciona. Quiero que se pueda ver la vista normalmente y que funcione el método buscar como el de generar el PDF; ahora si yo quito las clases funciona todo perfectamente, pero quiero hacerlo por clases ya que tengo muchas más vistas. el error es     **path('',include('ProyecBazarApp.urls') ),
File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\uni\taller\PROYECTO\DJANGO\ProyectoBAzar\ProyecBazarApp\views.py", line 86, in get
queryset = self.get_queryset()
File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\uni\taller\PROYECTO\DJANGO\ProyectoBAzar\ProyecBazarApp\views.py", line 33, in get_queryset
busqueda = self.request.GET.get('buscar')
AttributeError: 'MyView' object has no attribute 'request'**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
es el funcionamiento quiero lograr sin la clase me funciona el buscador y el generador de la vista del PDF, igual buscando me di cuenta de que estoy usando mal la clase y que tiene varias más tratare de corregirlo

Comment: Podrías ser más explicito con tu problema, que es lo que obtienes y cuál es el resultado esperado

Comment: @NSMichelJ el error por lo que entiendo es de request ahora no se como corregir eso, buscando me di cuenta que estoy usando mal las clases y voy a acomodarlo de nuevo ahora a ver si funciona 
 y lo que quiero es que en la página se pueda ver la lista de las cosas, que se pueda filtrar con el buscador y genere un pdf,  actualice el post con la info

Answer (score 0):

ya lo corregí estaba usando mal la clase y la función de pdf la saque para afuera así la puedo reutilizar en las otras clases:

```
class BoletaListView(ListView):
model = Boletas
template_name = 'ProyecBazarApp/informeBoleta.html'
paginate_by = 10

def get_queryset(self):
    busqueda = self.request.GET.get('buscar')
    busquedaF = self.request.GET.get('buscarFecha')
    campos_busqueda = ['id_boleta', 'total_boleta', 'usuario_FK__username']
    return self.buscar_campos(busqueda,busquedaF,campos_busqueda)

def buscar_campos(self, busqueda,busquedaF, campos):
    modelo = self.model.objects.all()
    if busqueda:
        queries = [Q(**{campo: busqueda}) for campo in campos]
        query = queries.pop()
        for item in queries:
            query |= item
        modelo = modelo.filter(query).distinct()
    elif busquedaF:
        query = Q(fecha_emision__icontains=busquedaF) 
        modelo = modelo.filter(query).distinct()
    return modelo

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    paginator = Paginator(context['object_list'], self.paginate_by)
    page = self.request.GET.get('page')
    context['object_list'] = paginator.get_page(page)
    return context
#--------------------PDF------------------------------------
def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Si se envió el formulario de generar PDF, se genera el PDF
    if self.request.method == 'POST' and 'informeBoletas_pdf' in self.request.POST:
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        generar_pdf_boletas(queryset)
    return self.get(self.request, *args, **kwargs)
```